# How to bind the useState() in React to dynamically generated <div> elements?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a widget in React which has a drop down in each block. I need to show a drop down on the click of a button in each respective list. But what is happening is, when i click the button all the drop down are showing up (of all the dynamically repeated elements).

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="widget">
          <h2>whats happeing</h2>
          <Block data={mock} /> //sub component which has the dropdown
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Block = props => {
  let blocks = [];
  let [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false); //currently i am trying to get this done with useState()

  if (props.data.length) {
    blocks = props.data.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <div key={item.id} className="block">
          <span
            className="dropdown-btn"
            onClick={() => setShowDropdown(!showDropdown)}
          >
            ▼
          </span>
          <div className="left-col">
            <p>{item.category}</p>
            <h3>
              <a href="#">{item.title}</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
          {showDropdown && <Dropdown />}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  return <div>{blocks}</div>;
};
```

This is the sandbox link to the code. Could you please let me know how to handle this in React ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/widget-with-drodown-kjovc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you only have 1 visible variable but you really need multiple. If you make a change like the following it will work properly

```
const Block = props => {
  let [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);
  const { category, title } = props.block;

  return (
    <>
      <span
        className="dropdown-btn"
        onClick={() => setShowDropdown(!showDropdown)}
      >
        ▼
      </span>
      <div className="left-col">
        <p>{category}</p>
        <h3>
          <a href="#">{title}</a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      {showDropdown && <Dropdown />}
    </>
  );
};

const Blocks = props => {
  let blocks = [];

  if (props.data.length) {
    blocks = props.data.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <div key={item.id} className="block">
          <Block block={item} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  return <div>{blocks}</div>;
};
export default Blocks;
```

Notice how we have moved the visible boolean into its own component

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your state accordingly to the id of items than it will impact the particular block so just change your state accordingly. you can see in below code

```
     return (
        <div key={item.id} className="block">
          <span
            className="dropdown-btn"
            onClick={() => setShowDropdown(item.id)}
          >
            ▼
          </span>
          <div className="left-col">
            <p>{item.category}</p>
            <h3>
              <a href="#">{item.title}</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
          {showDropdown === item.id && <Dropdown />}
        </div>
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dropdown will be controlled seperatly, then you need to keep in state only the id's you want to render a dropdown to. So, a way for doing it will be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./dropdown";

const Block = props => {
  let blocks = [];
  let [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState([]);

  const clickHandle = item => {
    let idIndex = showDropdown.indexOf(item);
    if (idIndex !== -1) {
      let newArray = [...showDropdown];
      newArray.splice(idIndex, 1);
      setShowDropdown(newArray);
    } else setShowDropdown([...showDropdown, item]);
  };

  if (props.data.length) {
    blocks = props.data.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <div key={item.id} className="block">
          <span className="dropdown-btn" onClick={() => clickHandle(item.id)}>
            ▼
          </span>
          <div className="left-col">
            <p>{item.category}</p>
            <h3>
              <a href="#">{item.title}</a>
            </h3>
          </div>
          {showDropdown.includes(item.id) && <Dropdown />}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  console.log(showDropdown);
  return <div>{blocks}</div>;
};
export default Block;
```